# Managing Python Packages using AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, python-packaging

I would like to use an Amazon S3 bucket to store python packages and use them in any `pip` installation in our project. As of now I am able to download these packages from web and store them in an Amazon S3 bucket using `aws s3 cp <source> <destination>`.

For example: `pip download tornado==6.2.0`. It has downloaded all the dependencies and copied into the S3 bucket. Real issue here is the dependencies are in either `.whl` or `tar.gz` or some other format.

How can I refer `pip install tornado==6.2.0` from S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is to implement the [simple python packaging index](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/), aka pyPI. If you configure a fileserver (which is what you're treating the bucket as) in the way decribed by the PEP, tools like `pip` will automatically know how to install packages from it.

But configuring a fileserver is hard and annoying, and other people have done it already anyway. So instead you can use [`pypiserver`](https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/) (which also publishes a docker container that you can run out of aws), and connect its package repository to the s3 bucket that you have set up (this part might actually be a bit tricky).

So, given that `pypiserver` runs on some port within your intranet, e.g. 3141, you can download packages from it with

```
pip install mypackage --extra-index-url 0.0.0.0:3141 --trusted-host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: thanks for response, i need to place pypiserver into cloud and behind loadbalancer/autoscaling group. This will cost more.

Comment: It looks to me you can use S3 with no servers and load balancers on your side. There is an old article on it https://www.novemberfive.co/blog/opensource-pypi-package-repository-tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
pip install https://s3.<Your-Region-ID>.amazonaws.com/<Your-Bucket-Name>/<Your-Package-Name>.zip
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: there will be multiple copies of same python dependency in each zip files.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a private bucket ?